# Tablet not detected by Android Studio

Tags: android, android-studio, android-4.4-kitkat

I am using Android Studio and a newbie. When I connect Samsung Galaxy S4 to download Android app, the Android Studio recognizes it but the muz uPad 7 is not detected although this tablet is detected by Windows 7. The developer option and USB debugging has already been enabled. What could be the problem ?

This tablet uses INTEL processor and 4.4.4 kitkat Android is installed but I could find only 4.4.2 in SDK manager. Could this be the problem ?

Comment: try settign the driver under driver setttings to google usb driver.

Comment: I downloaded Google USB driver and tried installing it but error showed up telling that driver cannot be installed.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Hey sujan_014 Android studion not recognizes your device means your device driver is not install properly. so for your tablet debugging you first install the your tablet device driver. if you haven't driver you can download from this website http://adbdriver.com/downloads/
first you connect your device to your pc and then start usb debugging. Now start the adbdriverinstaller setup and this will detect your device. After detecting device you should press the install button for installing your device driver.
After completing the process you can start debugging your device with android studio.

Comment: I installed adbdriver provided by you. Android Studio could not detect any of the devices connected to PC. It popped message saying that adb.exe  could not start. I had hard time figuring out what was the problem even after numerous trials and searching through internet. When I stopped the moborobo process from process manager, things were fine.. So I guess I will be using this driver.

Comment: @sujan_014 first install the adbdriver in your pc. start usb debugging from your device (if is not enable then go to setting-about phone-Build number=>touch 7 time to enable) and connect to the pc via cable. now adbdriver software detect your device. If your device named in red colour means your device driver is not install, and if it's greed means drivers are installed. If it is not then press install button to install the driver. it may take some time. I hop now it's work.

Answer (score 0):

Download driver from these site

http://moborobo.en.softonic.com/

http://www.techotopia.com/index.php/Testing_Android_Studio_Apps_on_a_Physical_Android_Device